# How can I make the columns and the rows fit the numbers I have imputed?

Tags: python, for-loop, encoding

[image]

Using the code from patterns1 try to modify it so you can take the following output. (spaces are optional).

Hi, I am new at python and I would like to know how to make the columns and the rows appear like in the picture. I have started the code but I don't know how to make the number I have inputted in a column. It would really help if you could tell me how.
This is the code I have written:

```
num1=eval(input("Enter number of rows: "))
num2=eval(input("Enter number of columns: "))
for i in range (0,num1): 
  for j in range (0,num2):
    print(i,j, end=" ")
print()
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Pass only `j` to first print function.` print(i, end=" ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to `print` `j` which is varying from `0` to `n-1`. The first loop is to print `num1` times and `j` is what output to `print`.

You also have an indentation issue with the second `print`. The right code should be:

```
num1=eval(input("Enter number of rows: "))
num2=eval(input("Enter number of columns: "))
for i in range (0,num1): 
    for j in range (0,num2):
        print(j, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: Awesome, @MaybelineLee. please accept the answer to mark the question as resolved.